# Get text from the listview

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I made a custom listview following the tutorial in this link 
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/23/how-to-create-a-custom-listbox-in-windows-phone-7/

and My need is I want to get the title and subtitle of each row when clicking on a particular row. Is there any way to get the text without taking it from the array from which it is supplied.

Comment: That link is such an ugly way of implementing that... Why not just create an object with a class and create a List/ObservableCollection of the object? Then you can just use simple binding and easily get the item you want via SelectedItem.

Comment: I am new to windows phone, can you provide me a link or some tutorial on that. It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Account
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string SubTitle { get; set; }
   public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListBox Margin="12,75,12,0" Name="L1"  SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                                <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SubTitle}" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

MainPage.xaml.cs
```

public ObservableCollection MyAccounts { get; set; }

```
public MainPage()
{
  Loaded += MainPageLoaded;
}
// Load data for the ViewModel Items
        private void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                MyAccounts = GenerateAccounts(); //populate your list
                L1.ItemsSource = MyAccounts;

        }

        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
               var lb = (ListBox)sender;
               if (lb.SelectedIndex == -1)return;
               var account = (Account)sender.SelectedItem;
              //get properties from Account npw.
              lb.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh, and here's a good sample: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/WP7-ListBox-SelectedItem